# Argument of \cventry has an extra }

Tags: moderncv, overleaf

I'm beginner in Latex and I'm trying to discover it by writing my CV. I'm having the error above while compiling the following source on writelatex.com, The compiler points me to the second cventry and I can't figure out the origin of the problem :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{jalal} % Your first name
\familyname{jillali} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
%\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{11, Rue 3}{hdidan, Maroc }
\mobile{(06) 56 95 15 97}
%\phone{(000) 111 1112}
%\fax{(000) 111 1113}
\email{jilal.jillali@gmail.com}
%\homepage{staff.org.edu/~jsmith}{staff.org.edu/$\sim$jsmith} % The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example
\extrainfo{24 ans, lalalal, permis C}
\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{picture} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)
%\quote{"A witty and playful quotation" - John Smith}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\cventry{2010--2013}{Ingénieur d'Etat en informatique}{Ecole Mohammadia d'Ingénieurs}{Rabat}{Option Ingénierie et Qualité Logicielles}
\cventry{2008--2010}{Classes Préparatoires  Mathématiques et Physiques Spéciales}{Lycée Omar  Ibn Abdelaziz }{Oujda,Morocco}
\section{Projet }

\cvitem{Title}{\emph{Money Is The Root Of All Evil -- Or Is It?}}
\cvitem{Supervisors}{Professor James Smith \& Associate Professor Jane Smith}
\cvitem{Description}{This thesis explored the idea that money has been the cause of untold anguish and suffering in the world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Experience}

\subsection{Vocational}

\cventry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}{Los Angeles}{}{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.
\newline{}\newline{}
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Learned how to make amazing coffee
\item Finally determined the reason for \textsc{PC LOAD LETTER}:
\begin{itemize}
\item Paper jam
\item Software issues:
\begin{itemize}
\item Word not sending the correct data to printer
\item Windows trying to print in letter format
\end{itemize}
\item Coffee spilled inside printer
\end{itemize}
\item Broke the office record for number of kitten pictures in cubicle
\end{itemize}}

%------------------------------------------------

\cventry{2010--2011}{Summer Intern}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}{Los Angeles}{}{Rated "truly distinctive" for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}

%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{Miscellaneous}

\cventry{2008--2009}{Computer Repair Specialist}{Buy More}{Burbank}{}{Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again.}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AWARDS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Awards}

\cvitem{2011}{School of Business Postgraduate Scholarship}
\cvitem{2010}{Top Achiever Award -- Commerce}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Computer skills}

\cvitem{Basic}{\textsc{java}, Adobe Illustrator}
\cvitem{Intermediate}{\textsc{python}, \textsc{html}, \LaTeX, OpenOffice, Linux, Microsoft Windows}
\cvitem{Advanced}{Computer Hardware and Support}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMMUNICATION SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Communication Skills}

\cvitem{2010}{Oral Presentation at the California Business Conference}
\cvitem{2009}{Poster at the Annual Business Conference in Oregon}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Languages}

\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Mothertongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Spanish}{Intermediate}{Conversationally fluent}
\cvitemwithcomment{Dutch}{Basic}{Basic words and phrases only}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Interests}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists

\cvlistdoubleitem{Piano}{Chess}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Cooking}{Dancing}
\cvlistitem{Running}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The macro `\cventry` wants six arguments;  in the first call you have five and in the second you have only four. Add `{}` to fill.

Comment: You're also missing an `\end{document}`, but I presume that that's a copy-paste error.

Comment: I would also suggest, for the purpose of your question here, to remove any personally identifying information. Thankfully, we're a pretty nice group of people, but this is public on the internet after all :)

Comment: @egreg could you please put your comment as an answer so I can mark it ? Thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: @kevin.arseneau thank you for the warning :) I will take it in consideration in future posts :)

Comment: @kevin.arseneau If it's too personal to be public on the internet, should it even be in a CV? As I see it, CVs should be public.

Comment: @Sverre ...I'm not sure about how others handle their CV, but I would think my phone and address are private. Visible on my CV but only to those I give a copy to (and protected by privacy laws in my home country). I do not, for example, include these details on my LinkedIn profile.

Comment: @kevin.arseneau Maybe it's different in the academic world. I've never seen an academic CV where people put their home address or private phone number. And not making your CV public partly defeats the purpose of having a CV - again, in the academic world. (And let's stop our discussion here, since it's off-topic).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The macro `\cventry` wants six arguments and you have just five and four in the first calls. Add `{}` in place of the appropriate argument, for instance

```
\cventry{2010--2013}
  {Ingénieur d'Etat en informatique}
  {Ecole Mohammadia d'Ingénieurs}
  {Rabat}
  {Option Ingénierie et Qualité Logicielles}
  {}
\cventry{2008--2010}
  {Classes Préparatoires Mathématiques et Physiques Spéciales}
  {Lycée Omar Ibn Abdelaziz}
  {Oujda,Morocco}
  {}
  {}
```

It helps having the arguments in separate lines as I did above.

Comment: Yes it's more readeable this way.